# C# app connection with Siemens S7-200

Tags: c#, plc, libnodave

I have an issue with getting data from PLC to PC. I have S7-200 and CP 243-1 communication module.

I need to read data from PLC. I have read a lot about `libnodave` library and tried to write an [app for myself](http://yadi.sk/d/6v0MjOH4LBFhw) for communication and downloaded sample in Vb [link on template](http://alexsentcha.wordpress.com/libnodave-exchange-data-with-siemens-plc-2/vb-net-exchange-data-with-siemens-plc/).

In my app I get exception error

> Cannot download DLL "libnodave.dll". Module not found.

But in references of project I added libnodave.net.dll... I have no idea.

All my attempts failed and maybe somebody know how to use libnodave or other libraries for communication PC with PLC Siemens S7-200. Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild shot, but is the `libnodave.dll` a native DLL and `libnodave.net.dll` a wrapper for this DLL?

Then you need to make sure that `libnodave.dll` is found on the search path. Ideally, you copy that DLL to the output folder of your project, so that both `libnodave.dll` and `libnodave.net.dll` are in the same folder. You can do this automatically by adding the native DLL to the root of your project (*not* referencing it, adding it like a normal existing file), setting its build type to "none" and "copy always". This will make sure the DLL is always copied to the bin/debug or bin/release folder.

As you can not add native DLLs as references to a .NET project, chances are the developers created a .NET wrapper that *can*  be added, but can't be used standalone. It will call functions in the native DLL by P/Invoke.

---

From the "link on template" page you linked:

> You need copy libnodave.net.dll file in the your PC and add references in the VB.NET project properties. This implements a bridge layer between libnodave.dll and applications written in MS .Net languages.

This means that my above guess seems to be right. You need both DLLs. The page continues to say:

> Also copy libnodave.dll in the same directory where is exe file is located.

---

PS: Please make sure to use to correct bittyness for your project. The native DLL might be 32-bit, so you might have to set the target platform from "Any CPU" to "x86" to make it work.

Comment: Really when I is change "Any CPU" to "x86" project have add libnodave.lib and compile without error. It lets continue try to read data from PLC. Thanks in my beginning.